# Use a Wordpress Page as a stylesheet?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'd like to be able to edit my WordPress theme's CSS by using a Page in the backend instead of the default `style.css` file. I've seen it done before as a page template but I can't seem to figure it out myself.

I'm using WordPress version 4.7.2 on a Multisite. I want the CSS to generate on theme activation, hence using a Page.

I apologize in advance if this is an easy fix and open to other ways to accomplish this. Thanks!

Comment: You want a custom field on all pages that control the CSS for that specific page?  Or do you want CSS that is applied to the entirety of the theme, from one page that is used only on back end?

Comment: CSS that is applied to the entirety of the theme from one page in the backend :) I know there are plugins but I want the page to be created on theme activation.

Comment: WordPress already has this feature available through the admin, [there is an editor that allows you to edit theme files](https://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Editor_Screen).

Comment: @hungerstar I am aware of this, but I would prefer it to be a page instead.

Comment: @Chelsea Why? What's the benefit? What makes a page preferable to how the admin version?

Comment: @hungerstar I am using a multisite so you can't access that unless you go through FTP. Some of the styles also get overwritten unless I put it in a Custom CSS plugin.

Comment: Please add specifications and details like that to your question. As it stands most people are going to assume you're working with a single install. Also, what version of WordPress are you running? _"Starting with WordPress 4.7, you can now add custom CSS to your own theme from the Customizer, without the need for additional plugins or directly editing themes and child themes."_

Comment: Also, themes are shared across the network. If two or more sites share the same theme (there's only one copy of theme files for _all_ sites using the same theme) then an update to one is an update to all. It looks like the best option is a plugin. Otherwise it looks like you're going to need a plugin as themes are shared acro

Comment: @hungerstar Apologies, post edited. Can the customizer automatically load the CSS once a theme is activated? This is my main issue.

Comment: From what I'm understanding is you're looking to have the same CSS shared across themes? Even when you change the theme? Basically, persistent multisite CSS?

Comment: No, I just want the CSS for that theme to be used once that theme is activated. If I change themes it will created new pages pertaining to the new theme with a completely different CSS page. Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: Nope. Not making sense for me. Maybe it will for someone else. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help anyways! :)

Comment: One last comment, ultimately it looks like you're going to need to do this through a plugin if you're not going to edit the theme's CSS yourself. You need the ability to set CSS per theme and that's something that a plugin would be able to do as directly editing theme files would (as noted before) update for all sites using that theme. A plugin is how you would circumvent  how Multisite uses shared theme files. This page that you're talking about is essentially a plugin. Whether you're using it to overwrite styles in `style.css` or add to it independently so they don't affect other sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend using a plugin, such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-add-custom-css/ or use the WordPress Customizer "Additional CSS" field.

However, to answer your question, this was easy since it's a modified way that I make some pages I load with ajax. You will need to create a page template and that requires FTP and a code editor to create the page and then push it your theme folder (hopefully a child theme or this template will go away when you upgrade).

I named my CSS page template: **css-page.php**

It requires only the opening php tag.

CODE for template css-page.php

```
<?php

/**
*
* Template Name: CSS page
* Not a recommended idea.
*
*/

header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

ob_start("compress");

//minify CSS
function compress( $minify ) {

    /* remove comments */
    $minify = preg_replace( '!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $minify );

    /* remove tabs, spaces, newlines, etc. */
    $minify = str_replace( array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $minify );

        return $minify;
}

//get the content
if (have_posts()) : 

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $content = get_the_content();

    $content = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $content );

    echo $content;

endwhile;

endif; 

ob_end_flush();
```

Then in your functions.php file in your child theme (or an include of that file or a custom plugin) paste in the following BUT change it where noted:

Change the value p='3134' to your page id where you're using this template. Change the id="something" to something else or remove it. Useful to have an id or a class for js manipulation.

**For functions.php**

```
//Get CSS page contents
function myprefix_page_css() {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" id="something" href="'. site_url() .'/?p=3134" type="text/css" media="screen">';
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'myprefix_page_css', 99 );
```